# jQuery Not working in VS2010

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi I am new to VS2010 and I was experimenting with JavaScript in ASP.NET. I have tried referencing my sample scripts but they are not working, why is that?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Member_supplier_details.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $("div").animate({ left: '250px' });
        });
    });
</script> 
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <button>Start Animation</button>
<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>
     <!-- <input name="Qty" type="text" id="Text1" value="0" size="3" tabindex="2000" class="spinner" /> -->
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "They not working" how? Do you get some kind of error?

Comment: Your code working to my side !! what is your exact problem here ?

Comment: No problem in jQuery code- see here exact- http://jsfiddle.net/stackrahul/vQ4re/

Comment: [The button element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) - Check the `type` section and then you should be able to find the problem :)

Comment: @Manoz You've missed the `<form />` around the `<button />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your button code. becoz button without type is submit so your  page is submited. so change your type to button.

```
 <button type="button">Start Animation</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Button and DIV they do not have IDs'. You need to give them ID in html tag, then use those id's in javascript to do the changes